# If $x$ is irrational, can $-x^3+x^2+x$ be rational?

Tags: polynomials

I was wondering if this was true. I am not quite sure how to aproach this, other than proving that $x+x^2$ is irrational.

Comment: Yes, it could be even zero, which is rational. Of course not for all irrational $x$. Take $x=\pi$. Then no polynomial in $\pi$ is rational. Could you clarify what you mean by "if $x$ is irrational"? Does there *exists* an irrational $x$?

Comment: Hint: consider the roots of the polynomial $-x^3+x^2+x+
17$.

Answer (score 4):

$-x^3+x^2+x=-x(x^2-x-1)$. The second factor has a root at $\phi$ (golden ratio), so the answer is yes.

Comment: But only for a very specific $x$. The title asks for any irrational $x$.

Comment: It ask if it is possible at all, I gave an example. Of course not for all $x$.

Comment: I see. But then the question is trivial, isn't it?

Comment: Eh, people have different levels of knowledge. I found it fun to think about.

Comment: Depends on the people again. This is basically a nice first semester question. I have seen other questions I could hardly parse that were answered in similar time. As long as a question is asked out of curiosity and in good faith, it is fine for me. We are not on MO, the questions don't have to need a degree to answer ;)

Comment: Right, I see your point.

Comment: This is the answer to the question as posed. I  think it is a good one and should stay +1

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to show there are infinitely many such cases where irrational $x$ lead to representing a rational number. Probably there are other ways, but hopefully this is fun.

To show there are infinitely many cases, it's sufficient to look at the roots of $f(x)=-x^3+x^2+x+1+3r$ for any rational $r$ with denominator relatively prime to $3$. We know it has a real root because it's odd degree, let's prove the root is not rational.

Suppose it does have a rational root, then its denominator can't be divisible by $3$ since it would leave $x^3 = x^2+x+1+3r$ inconsistent, as $x^3$ has a strictly larger power of $3$ in its denominator than the right hand side of the equation, which is a contradiction. (Adding numbers can only lower or maintain the power of $3$ in the denominator - this may also be recognized as an application of the ultrametric property of p-adic number theory.)

This is good, that means we can look at reducing it modulo $3$. This is simple enough to check by simply plugging in $x=0,1,2$ and seeing we can't factor off a linear term. Since it can't even reduce modulo $3$, it can't reduce over rationals either, which wraps it up.

Now we have that $-x^3+x^2+x+1+3r=0$ is irreducible over the rationals with at least one real root which must be irrational. So for infinitely many rational $r$ with denominator not divisible by $3$, there is a non-rational real $x$ such that $-x^3+x^2+x=-1-3r$.